# Common legend for several geom area ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot with several geom_area according to the following code :

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, 10, 2), 100, 1))

dat_density <- data.frame(density(dat[, 1])[c("x", "y")])
quant <- quantile(dat[, 1], probs = seq(0, 1, 0.10))
library(RColorBrewer)
color_pal <- brewer.pal(length(quant)-1, "RdYlBu")

dens <- ggplot(data = dat_density, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_line(size = 2)
for(i in 1:(length(color_pal))){
  dens <- dens +
  geom_area(data = subset(dat_density, x > quant[[i]] & x < quant[[i + 1]]), fill = color_pal[i])
  }
dens
```

How can I add a common legend with each color of the `color_pal` vector (corresponding to all the 10% area of data) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to define the groups in your dataset

```
dat_density$quant <- cut(dat_density$x, breaks = c(-Inf, quant, Inf))
ggplot(data = dat_density, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = quant)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu")
```

Comment: Ok,it works well. It just needs to improve the labels now :)

Comment: Note, to avoid discontinuities in the `geom_line`, the aestethics `fill = quant` should be provided in the `geom_area` and not in the general ones. `geom_line` can also be added after the `geom_area`.